# XSLT Find preceeding text node in mixed content element

Tags: xml, xslt

How can i find the text node that directly preceeds the "specialElem"-element ("Foo-" in this example)? While all other whitespaces inside the "main"-element shall be preserved, the whitespaces in front of the "specialElem"-element shall be removed.

```
<main>
   Foo Foo 
   <someElem>
   Foo Foo
   </someElem>
   Foo Foo 
   <otherElem>
       <subElem>
           Foo Foo 
       </subElem>
   </otherElem>
   Foo-        <!-- the whitespaces here shall be removed -->
   <specialElem>
       Bar!
   <specialElem/>
   Foo Foo
</main>
```

Desired output:

Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo **Foo-Bar!** Foo Foo

Thnaks in advance!

Comment: Could you give us a real-world example of what you need this for? It seems like a bit of a strange requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you close properly the `<specialElem>` tag and remove the comment, then:

```
/main/text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::specialElem]]
```

will select the requested text node/s.

--
Not quite sure what your requested output format is.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work. Could you please explain the selector expression in normal language?

Comment: @Schinski Select the text node/s (child of `main`) whose immediate following sibling is a `specialElem` element.